# Group data by date

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have data that includes type of data, amount and date it belongs to.
Now i already get the correct form of data i just want to "group" it up in different arrays

For easier understanding here is a link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dik9d1?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with demo data.

If you take a look there are 0 values at type's that have no data at the date the others do... Now i want the ones who do have the same date in common to have values of the other's where there is 0.

the desired result in this case would be

`Types1 = 100,100,70`, `Types2 = 80,0,0`, `Types1 = 0,0,90`

(since there are 3 unique dates)

Comment: How would you decide that in second types2 value must be 80,0,0 meansa length of type2 is 3, How would you decide ?

Comment: yes the length is 3 and its the same for the other 2...i want the length to be decided by the amount of unique dates...in this case thats 3....and so i want to make it that if the types have same date they need to be in the same row

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ia5lX2O is this your desired output ?

Comment: Yes ! yes it is..... I already worked it out but i think i complicated it too much so i would still like to see your answer

Comment: Is it right for You ?

Comment: It does work yes but theres way 2 much code...i just used  array.splice function in an if loop and it did the job :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240301/discussion-between-grd-and-bteck).